# how to install windows desktop application (.exe) using Azure DevOps?

Tags: bash, command-line, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, continuous-deployment

I am using Azure DevOps for my automation build, I can build my visual studio project using script and run that script using bash task of Azure DevOps.

Now I have my `.exe` file into artifacts, So my question is like does Azure DevOps have any task which can help me to install my application on to remote machine?

If Azure don't have any task than how I can do it using command line as when I install it using wizard there is lot of questions I need to answer while doing installation like path and all.

Answer (score 1):

You can run an `.exe` file with the command line task and give him the `.exe` path.

But, if the installation is in UI and need user inputs you **can't** do it automatically with Azure DevOps, you need to edit your code and supports also command-line installation (with flags for the inputs, for example `my-app.exe -path "c:/myFodler"`).

Comment: how to handle popup with update version , as it ask for Yes or No

Comment: You can't, you need to edit the installation that will be without popup